# Archive for required library: 'lib/Chrome/chromedriver' in project 'XYZ' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file using ChromeDriver Selenium Java

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven, selenium

Trying to invoke Chrome driver from Selenium JAVA project in Eclipse, getting a build error.

**Actions Tried:**

- `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","//Path//chromedriver");`
- Added Executables to `PATH` variable.
- Added the executable Chrome driver `.exe` to build path.

Still getting the build error. As mentioned in the error the chrome driver `.exe` is present in the path.

**Error:**

> Archive for required library: 'lib/Chrome/chromedriver' in project 'FirstSeleniumTest' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file   FirstSeleniumTest       Build path  Build Path Problem

Answer (score 0):

One of the common problems for automation folks. You can solve this problem by following ways:

1. Keep ChromeDriver exe into project root. No need to do anything.
2. if you keep ChromeDriver in ProjectRoo/resources then you have to use 
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.seprator+"resources/chromedriver.exe");

**In your step 1** - you missed **.exe** extension. 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","//Path//chromedriver.exe");

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Still getting the below error when i placed .exe file in project root folder.
java.lang.module.FindException: Module format not recognized -- Path of .exe file

As using it in MAC not providing .exe for the file.

Comment: Sharing one work around with you. Use WebDriverManager APO which automatically manage your webdrivers. 
   https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager 
   WebDriverManager.chromedriver().proxy("--proxy-server=https://10.1:8080").setup();

driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Archive for required library: 'lib/Chrome/chromedriver' in project 'FirstSeleniumTest' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

---

This issue is observed because of conflicting libraries and in majority of the cases when [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) is being used as a build tool. Possibly the existing libraries in the local (maven) repository are erroneous and maven tries to open, which fails.

---

### Solution

The following steps will solve the issue:

- Ensure that **JDK** in your system and in the eclipse points to the same version.
- Delete all the **jar** files from `Libs` directory then *copy* -> *paste* the original Jars again. Finally do a `Clean` -> `Rebuild`
- (In case using **maven**) Delete the corresponding maven download folder i.e. `.m2` and do `maven` -> `update project` in eclipse.
- (In case using **maven**) Sometimes deleting only the `/.m2/repository` works.
- At times simply *Close* and *Reopen* the project also works.
- Try to use *Eclipse* without `m2e` features.
- As you are using [macos](/questions/tagged/macos) you don't need to add the extension i.e. **`.exe`** (like Windows) as follows:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/path/to/chromedriver");
  ```

---

### tl; dr

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Cannot be Read or is Not a Valid ZIP file – How to fix Maven Build Path Error with corrupted .jar file](https://crunchify.com/cannot-be-read-or-is-not-a-valid-zip-file-how-to-fix-maven-build-path-error-with-corrupted-jar-file/)
- [Bug 375249 - Eclipse throws "cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file" error for a completely healthy jar file on the build path](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375249)

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved , needed to switch chromedriver.exe file to executable and was adding to .exe file to build path which was not required.

Comment: Isn't that what I exactly mentioned in the last bullet point of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59054788/archive-for-required-library-lib-chrome-chromedriver-in-project-xyz-cannot/59065789#59065789) `As you are using macos you don't need to add the extension i.e. .exe (like Windows) as follows`?